# How to get task in Spring @Async Method

Tags: java, asynchronous, spring-async

How to get task in Spring @Async Method? because I want to return FutureTask, but Constructor of the futureTask need to pass Runnable or Callable parameter.

**Before**

```
@Component
public class ConversionProcessor {
    @Async
    public Future<String> convert() {
        //doing something

        return new AsyncResult<>("Hello");
    }
}
```

**Expected**

```
@Component
public class ConversionProcessor {
    @Async
    public FutureTask convert() {
       //doing something

       return new FutureTask(); 
       // compiler error, 'cannot resolve constructor FutureTask()'
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's the excuse for not passing `Callable`?

Comment: @BranislavLazic Actually, I don't want to implement `Callable`, just want to use Async annotation, so that I cannot log exception stack trace if throwing unhandle exception in async method. the exception will be stored in FutureTask.outcome attribute.

Comment: I get answer from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async 5. Exception Handling 
"When a method return type is a Future, exception handling is easy – Future.get() method will throw the exception."